# How can I scale/map series data from initial range to [0-1] time range

Tags: python, pandas, normalization

I have various pandas Series of different length and I want to normalize them in order to be in a standard [0-1] time frame so I can operate on them  the right way. I tried a temporal modulation method and the implementation is given below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
class Demo:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.y = data
        self.x = np.linspace(0, len(data)-1, num=len(data), endpoint=True)
        
        self.inter_f = interp1d(self.x, self.y, kind='cubic') 
        
        self.length = len(data)-1
        self.z_bar = 1/(len(data)-1)
        
    def get_cubic_data_from_z_point(self,z):
        return float(self.inter_f(z * self.length))
    
    def get_N_samples(self,N):
        n_samples = []
        z_samples = np.linspace(0,1,N)

        for z in z_samples:
           n_samples.append(self.get_cubic_data_from_z_point(z))

        return n_samples
data1 = pd.Series(list(np.random.rand(1000)))
data2 = pd.Series(list(np.random.rand(1002)))

demo = Demo(data1)
sampled = demo.get_N_samples(10)
```

I would like to ask if there is a library that perform this operation efficiently and faster.

Comment: This code does not seem really slow. It runs in 1 ms on my machine.

Comment: I really want to thank you for the time you spend on it(its my first ever question after all :P)  For the time being I will work with this!